# How can I change font style of current text of a docx or PDF file using python

Tags: python, pdf, docx

I am facing an issue while extracting text from pdf and word file that the character extracting is different from actual character present in a file like 0 is extracting as @ or any other special character.

Thus am thinking of changing their font style to aerial or anything like normal, so that I will be able to extract the same text.
How can I change the font style of a word/pdf file using python? Any leads?

Comment: Share your code and errors

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili am not able to find anything to change the font style